# Is it possible to transfer a character to another local ps3 account for coop

Tags: diablo-iii, ps3

I was wondering if it's somehow possible to transfer one of my chars to another local ps3 account for split screen coop.

I recently played a lot with some friends here at home and we made the mistake of creating two of the chars we are using on the same local playstation account. Unfortunately only progress for one of the chars is saved.

Is it possible to create a new playstation account and transfer the existing char to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to copy entire Diablo 3 save games to other PS3 users (you can't do it per character).

In the games section of your PS3 there is an option called "PS3 save utility" (or something like that (I'm not at home right now)), which lets you copy saves to different users, or to a USB stick. From that moment on you will both have the same characters. However these aren't merged back so you can use them individually.

Be careful you don't copy the wrong way around though, you might overwrite the wrong user.